# AutoFilter method of Range class failed.Copy from all sheets after filter

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy-paste

i am a beginner at vba please i need help with this error.
I am trying to Autofilter all sheets in my workbork using a cell value in on my dashboard.Then copy all visible cells in range A2:E100 from all sheet after autofilter and paste on my Sheet called dashboard.

Here is what i have so far.

```
Sub AggregateAfterfilter()
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("A9000").End(xlUp).Row

     ' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
    ' Dashboard worksheet also exclude sheet called Lists.
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> "Dashboard" And sh.Name <> "lists" Then

            With sh

                'error occurs on the line below
                .Range("$A$1:$Q$100").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="=" & Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B45").Value, Operator:=xlAnd
                .Range("A2:E100" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

                With Sheets("Dashboard").Cells(lastRow + 1, "A")
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End With

            End With

        End If

    Next sh

    Sheets("Dashboard").Select Range("A44").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help in advance

Comment: Range("$A$1:$Q$100").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="=", Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B45").Value, Operator:=xlAnd

Comment: @Poof that is the line error occurs on.

Answer (score 0):

Because you aren't filtering two different Criteria change Operator:=xlAnd to

```
Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: thanks for your effort. I have changed it to what you suggested but still getting the same error.

Comment: The only other thing that may cause a problem, that I can see, is trying to reference the value on the Dashboard Worksheet.  I would try setting a variable earlier on in the code for that value and see and then call out that value.

x = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B45").Value and replace the call out in the criteria with x